# Checking if number already exists

Tags: java

I am generating a random number between 40 and 50. Once the number is generated I print it to the screen and I add it to a `ArrayList`. However if the number already exists in the `ArrayList` then I print a message `"This number already exists in Array List"`. So the code should never print the same number twice. However for some reason it keeps printing the same number twice even when it exists in the array list. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong here

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random; 

public class RandomNumber {

    Random random = new Random(); 
    int x;
    int l;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomNumber r = new RandomNumber();
        r.genNumber(50,40);
    }

    public void genNumber(int high, int low) {
        x = random.nextInt(high-low)+low;
        ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();


        if(!arl.contains(x)) {
            System.out.println(x);
            arl.add(x);

        } else if (arl.contains(x)) {
            System.out.println("This is already in ArrayList");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You just generate 1 random number in your main method. How would a number even exist before in the ArrayList

Comment: Say if I call the method multiple times then the same number should not print twice

Comment: `!arl.contains(x)` is always `true` because the list is empty when you examine this condition -- you create the list on the line above the check.

Comment: So how can I modify it so that the same number is never printed twice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the ArrayList a field, instead of a local variable. This way it can be reused between method calls (as long as you use the same instance of RandomNumber). In your current implementation, the ArrayList that keeps track of already generated numbers is thrown away at the end of the method.

This works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

public class RandomNumber {

    Random random = new Random();
    int x;
    int l;
    ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomNumber r = new RandomNumber();
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);

        //r = new RandomNumber(); // created a new one - uncommenting this line will mean the List is lost and we will generate duplicates.
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
        r.genNumber(50,40);
    }

    public void genNumber(int high, int low){
        x = random.nextInt(high-low)+low;

        if(!arl.contains(x)){
            System.out.println(x);
            arl.add(x);

        }else if(arl.contains(x)){
            System.out.println("This is already in ArrayList");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Still printing the same number twice

Comment: Yes only because he is creating a new object of the class

Comment: try removing this line - "r = new RandomNumber(); // created a new one...". I added it to demonstrate that if you create another instance, it will generate the same numbers twice. You have to use the same RandomNumber object.

Comment: I have commented the line out for you - try it now

Comment: So does this mean every time I run the code the ArrayList would have nothing in it? if I only had one RandomNumber r = new RandomNumber();
        r.genNumber(50,40);

Comment: The ArrayList will gain one new element every time you call genNumber() and a new number is successfully generated. Every time you run the code, it will reset to have nothing in it.

Comment: Oh now everything makes sense. I thought ArrayList always saved data from last run. Thanks for clearing up! will choose this best answer as soon as it lets me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The logic in your code is broken.

First, when you check `if(!arl.contains(x))`, `arl` is empty, so this condition is always true.

More importantly, if you want to maintain just unique numbers, use a `Set` instead of a `List`. And this set should be **global**, i.e., declared outside the `genNumber` method. The code below should work (untested, and I kept your original data structures).

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random; 

public class RandomNumber {

    Random random = new Random(); 
    int x;
    int l;
    ArrayList<Integer> arl;

    public RandomNumber() {
        arl = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        RandomNumber r = new RandomNumber();
        r.genNumber(50,40);
    }

    public void genNumber(int high, int low){
        x = random.nextInt(high-low)+low;
        if(!arl.contains(x)) {
            System.out.println(x);
            arl.add(x);
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is already in ArrayList");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Actually I think you're misunderstanding the error. You are making a brand new ArrayList every time you call your method, so it always starts out empty. So, no problem adding the random number to it.

To fix, you'll want to move your arl out of that method so that it is created once and lives on until your app is done (or until you're done storing random numbers).

Comment: ArrayList<Integer> arl = new ArrayList<Integer>(); I moved this outside the method, but still same result